# Can I put this INSERT and DELETE query into a single INSERT query

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, duplicates

How can I put this into one query, the key point is that when grouping artist by name I need to consider all rows in `artist`, but I don't want to keep rows in `artist_nodup` table if it already is in `mbartist_discogsartist` table. (I'm using Postgres 9.3)

```
INSERT INTO artist_nodup
SELECT
min(a1.id) as id,
a1.name
FROM artist  a1
GROUP BY a1.name
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
;

DELETE
FROM artist_nodup T1
WHERE exists
( select 1
   from mbartist_discogsartist T2
  where t1.id = t2.discogs_id
)
;
```

Comment: You can create stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's enough to avoid the redundant rows in the `INSERT` and there is no need to delete previously existing rows from `artist_nodup` as well:

```
INSERT INTO artist_nodup
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM   artist a
LEFT   JOIN artist a2 ON a2.name = a.name AND a2.id <> a.id
LEFT   JOIN mbartist_discogsartist m ON m.discogs_id = a.id
WHERE  a2.name IS NULL
AND    m.discogs_id IS NULL;
```

The 1st `LEFT JOIN` rules out rows from `artist` where other rows exist with the same name.
The 2nd `LEFT JOIN` rules out rows from `artist` where a matching id exists in `mbartist_discogsartist` (***replacing*** the later `DELETE`).

`LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` is one of a couple of techniques to do this:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

If you also want to rule out pre-existing rows in `artist_nodup`:

```
...
LEFT JOIN artist_nodup an ON an.name = a.name
...
AND an.name IS NULL
```

You get the drill ...

Comment: Im well viewed in the 2nd LEFT JOIN usage, but the first is interesting I never thought of that instead of GROUP BY HAVING COUNT(*)=1, but what do you mean by 'If it's enough to avoid the redundant rows in the INSERT' ?

Comment: Your original `DELETE` would also delete pre-exsisting, offending rows in `artist_nodup`, which my answer does not.

Comment: thats 'and there is no need to delete previously existing rows from artist_nodup as well:' but what does 'If it's enough to avoid the redundant rows in the INSERT' mean ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor: Your original example inserts some redundant rows, which are then deleted again. My query does not insert the rows to begin with - *avoids the redundant rows* -  which is considerably cheaper and should normally be the superior solution. But it may not be 100 % the same thing, for instance if there are triggers on `artist_nodup`.

Comment: ah understand, yeah the reason why I did the delete is because I couldnt work out to do the group by over the whole but only insert where not already in other table, thanks again the solution is just what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Stored Procedure`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_InsertDelete
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO artist_nodup
    SELECT
    min(a1.id) as id,
    a1.name
    FROM artist  a1
    GROUP BY a1.name
    HAVING COUNT(*)=1
    ;
    GO
    DELETE
    FROM artist_nodup T1
    WHERE exists
    ( select 1
       from mbartist_discogsartist T2
      where t1.id = t2.discogs_id
    )
    ;
END
```

And to use both queries you can call new created stored procedure: `EXECUTE sp_InsertDelete`

---

Or you can create `TRIGGER` on `artist_nodup` table. It automatically will use delete query when something will be inserted to `artist_nodup` table.

*Note: If you need to use delete query only after provided insert query, this wont work for you, that because this delete query always will be used after anything will be inserted.*

```
CREATE TRIGGER AutoDelete ON artist_nodup 
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
     DELETE
     FROM artist_nodup T1
     WHERE exists
     ( select 1
        from mbartist_discogsartist T2
       where t1.id = t2.discogs_id
     )
     ;   
END;
```

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a pure sql solution, is that not possible

Comment: Triggers and stored procedures are all "pure SQL."  Not every operation is designed to be done in a single statement.  Likely what you want to do is put your commands into a text file, and then feed that psql such as:  `psql -q dbname < mycommands.txt`  In this way, you can execute both operations with a single command.

Comment: No I was looking for efficiency and simplicity and your stored procedure still runs two queries instead of 1 and is more complex so its not any improvement for me, but thanks anyway.